# JavaFX TreeView - repaint node when its underlying data changes

Tags: javafx, data-binding, treeview

I have a `TreeView<Node>`, containing `TreeItem<Node>`s.

The `Node` class has a field:

```
private final CashflowSet cashflowSet = new CashflowSet();
```

and the `CashflowSet` in turn contains an observable list property of `Cashflow`s:

```
private final SimpleListProperty<Cashflow> cashflows = new SimpleListProperty<>(observableArrayList());
```

*(Don't bother why I have it nested like this; both the Node class and the CashflowSet class have various other fields, which aren't relevant here)*

Also, I have a custom cell factory for the tree:

```
tree.setCellFactory(cell -> new NodeRenderer());
```

which displays the count of cashflows on each node:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Node node, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(node, empty);

    if (node == null || empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
        setText(null);
    } else {
        int cashflowCount = node.getCashflowSet().getCashflows().size();
        label.setText(String.valueOf(cashflowCount));
        setGraphic(label);
    }
}
```

*(the cell factory renders other things too, but again I left out everything that is not relevant here)*

Now, when I add/remove cashflows in my data model, I find the appropriate `Node` and add/remove the cashflow to/from its observable cashflow list, e.g.:

```
treeItem.getValue().getCashflowSet().addCashflow(cashflow);
```

**My problem:** When cashflows are added or removed in a node's cashflow set, the renderer doesn't repaint the node, so it still shows the outdated cashflow count. Only when I force the tree to repaint, e.g. by collapsing and expanding the nodes, it will show the updated data. I understand that the tree doesn't automatically repaint the node because it isn't notified about these changes of the underlying data. And I would know how to fix this for example for a ListView or TableView, where the items are bound to an observable list, and I could just define extractors on various properties that would trigger when the properties change. But a TreeView's data model is different and I'm not sure what the proper solution is here. Do I have to manually add listeners somewhere? Or even `bind()` the `label` of my renderer the the `sizeProperty()` of the observable cashflow list? I don't understand well enough how these cell factories work, so I'm not sure if it is the correct place for something like this.

I know that I could just call `refresh()` on the tree, however the tree can contain a lot of data, and I would like to have good performance, and refreshing the whole thing whenever anything changes in a single node seems like a poor solution.

**So my Question is this:** How can I let the tree trigger the repaint of a particular node, whenever the node's underlying cashflow list changes (i.e.: cashflows are removed or added). *(Note that the cashflow objects themselves don't change, so I really just need to watch changes in the list's size, not in the list's elements)*

Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra There's nothing to "reproduce" here. I'm not describing a bug, I have described the relevant parts of my application and I'm asking what features the JavaFX framework provides that I can use to achieve my goal.

Comment: @user3237736 its not about reproducing/bug/.. or whatsoever. You have the context. But others dont have one.  Others need an example to run and check what can be done to fix the issue.

Comment: _There's nothing to "reproduce" here_ that would be true only if the solution would be a simple oversight (not seeing api meant to be used or such) on your part. For anything more complex, answerers __have__ to reproduce the issue then play with options until they are satisfied to have found something that's worth keeping for future readers (which are __the__ focus of this knowledge base). Not providing a [mcve] a) leaves writing it to potential answerers which b) might keep some off even trying or c) coming up with something that doesn't fit (drawing comments like _no that's not what .._

Comment: also: reducing complexity by breaking up problems into small separate parts and solving them one-by-one is a important (I would say _most_ important, mileage could vary, though ;) solution strategy. Only if we find and understand the small stumbling stones can we expect to solve the real things. Writing a [mcve] helps to clear the fog and focus. Also it's easier for readers to scan simple code than to wade through verbal descriptions (that might tend to distract from the real issue, as it seems to do here, IMO). In short: I really don't understand the reluctance of askers to write it ;)

Comment: @jewelsea The fireEvent() call is the best solution for me, since I already have the exact nodes at hand when I add or remove to/from their cashflow list. The VALUE_CHANGED_EVENT is private though, but there's a public static method for it. So my solution is:

`Event.fireEvent(node, new TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<>(TreeItem.valueChangedEvent(), node, node.getValue()));`

IT seems I cannot accept a comment as a solution to the thread though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential solutions:

1. When the data is updated, either:

   a) Change the treeItem.

   - [Create a new TreeItem based on the updated data](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#%3Cinit%3E(T)) and replace the existing one with that.

   OR

   b) Fire a [tree item value change event](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#valueChangedEvent()) on the existing tree item.

OR

<s>2. Subclass tree item and [override its value property](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/fdc88341f1df8fb9c99356ada54b25124b77ea6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.java#L457) with a custom property implementation aware of your changes.</s>

As noted by James_D in comments, option 2 won't work because the value property is private, so it cannot be overridden.

Example code is supplied for potential approach 1b.

This code will fire a change event on an existing tree item whenever the size of a given list associated with a value of the tree item changes.

```
Bindings.size(
    treeItem.getValue().getCashflowSet().getCashflows()
).addListener((o, old, new) -> 
    Event.fireEvent(
        treeItem, 
        new TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<>(
            TreeItem.valueChangedEvent(), 
            treeItem, 
            treeItem.getValue()
        )
    )
);
```

You would also need to remove the listener when you wish to invalidate the binding (e.g. the tree item value changes), and potentially reassociate the item with a new binding.

**Example**

Example code is based on demo code from Sai's answer and includes logic for removing stale bindings and creating new bindings when the value associated with the tree item changes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class TreeViewDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Task demoTask;
    private TreeItem<Task> demoTreeItem;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // BUILD DATA
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            Task sub1 = new Task("Sub Task A", rnd.nextBoolean());
            Task sub2 = new Task("Sub Task B", rnd.nextBoolean());

            Task tsk = new Task("Task " + i, rnd.nextBoolean());
            if (demoTask == null) {
                tsk.setName("Demo Task");
                demoTask = tsk;
            }
            tsk.getTasks().addAll(sub1, sub2);
            tasks.addAll(tsk);
        }

        // BUILD TREE ITEMS
        TreeItem<Task> rootItem = new MyTreeItem();
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            TreeItem<Task> item = new MyTreeItem(task);

            for (Task subTask : task.getTasks()) {
                TreeItem<Task> subItem = new MyTreeItem(subTask);
                item.getChildren().add(subItem);

                if (subTask == demoTask) {
                    demoTreeItem = subItem;
                }
            }

            if (task == demoTask) {
                demoTreeItem = item;
            }

            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        TreeView<Task> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        treeView.setRoot(rootItem);
        treeView.setCellFactory(taskTreeView -> new MyTreeCell());

        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> demoTask.getCashFlows().add(1));

        Button changeButton = new Button("Change Task");
        changeButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            demoTask = createChangeTask();
            demoTreeItem.setValue(demoTask);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(addButton, changeButton, treeView);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeView Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Task createChangeTask() {
        Task changeTask = new Task("Change It", false);

        changeTask.getCashFlows().add(1);
        changeTask.getCashFlows().add(2);

        return changeTask;
    }

    class MyTreeItem extends TreeItem<Task> {
        public MyTreeItem() {
            super();
        }

        public MyTreeItem(Task value) {
            super(value);
            establishBindingForValueProperty();
            establishBindingForCashflowSize(null, value);
        }

        private void establishBindingForCashflowSize(Task oldValue, Task newValue) {
            // remove old size binding listener, so that if the cashflow associated with the old task changes,
            // it no longer triggers a value change event on this TreeItem.
            if (oldValue != null) {
                sizeBinding.removeListener(sizeBindingListener);
                sizeBinding = null;
                sizeBindingListener = null;
            }

            // create a new size binding listener, so that when the cashflow associated with the task changes,
            // it triggers a value change event on this TreeItem.
            if (newValue != null) {
                sizeBinding = Bindings.size(
                        getValue().getCashFlows()
                );

                sizeBindingListener = (observable1, oldValue1, newValue1) -> Event.fireEvent(
                        MyTreeItem.this,
                        new TreeModificationEvent<>(
                                TreeItem.valueChangedEvent(),
                                MyTreeItem.this,
                                getValue()
                        )
                );

                sizeBinding.addListener(sizeBindingListener);
            }
        }

        private IntegerBinding sizeBinding;
        private ChangeListener<Number> sizeBindingListener;
        private void establishBindingForValueProperty() {
            valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                    establishBindingForCashflowSize(oldValue, newValue)
            );
        }
    }

    class MyTreeCell extends TreeCell<Task> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Task item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null && !empty) {
                setText(item.getName() + " (" + item.getCashFlows().size() + ")");
            } else {
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    }

    class Task {
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        BooleanProperty completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ObservableList<Integer> cashFlows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public Task(String n, boolean c) {
            setName(n);
            setCompleted(c);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public boolean isCompleted() {
            return completed.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty completedProperty() {
            return completed;
        }

        public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
            this.completed.set(completed);
        }

        public ObservableList<Task> getTasks() {
            return tasks;
        }

        public ObservableList<Integer> getCashFlows() {
            return cashFlows;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For 2., the method you linked is final, so can’t be overridden (unless I am missing the intention of that idea)

Comment: @James_D so it is . . . that won't work :-).  I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: hmm.. you have to update the binding if the value changes.. do you? (real question, it's getting a bit late here, might have overlooked something ;)

Comment: I think you do need to update the binding if the value changes, but then I may have overlooked something too :-) I added some sample code based on Sai's example code, pre-extractor update (it's super ugly :-), overall Sai's approach based on your extractor suggestion looks better to me.

Comment: As I stated in jewelsea's initial commit, I just went for the solution of firing an event manually. I anyway have to traverse the nodes for some other logic, so I have the node at hand when I update it. So I didn't have to do any bindings in my case

Answer (score 2):

One way to address this issue is by adding listener to the 'cashFlows' list in the TreeCell constructor.

```
public MyTreeCell() {
    ListChangeListener<? super Integer> listener = p -> updateItem(getItem(), false);
    itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        if (oldItem != null) {
            oldItem.getCashFlows().removeListener(listener);
        }
        if (newItem != null) {
            newItem.getCashFlows().addListener(listener);
        }
    });
}
```

In the above code, you register a listener to the cashFlows of the item associated to each cell. So every time an update occurs on the list (cashFlows), will call the updateItem to re-evaluate the display.

**[UPDATE]:**

Based on the comments and suggestions, I gave a try by including an extractor implementation to TreeItem to fire the value changed event. And it worked well :). So pretty much this is the implementation for what @kleopatra and @jewelsea are mentionting. With this, you can just list all the observable properties that you want to monitor and update the cell.

```
Callback<Task, Observable[]> extractor = task -> new Observable[]{task.getCashFlows()};

class MyTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T> {
        public MyTreeItem(Callback<T, Observable[]> extractor) {
            if (extractor == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Extractor cannot be null");
            }
            final InvalidationListener listener = e -> Event.fireEvent(this, new TreeModificationEvent<>(TreeItem.<T>valueChangedEvent(), this, getValue()));
            valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (oldValue != null) {
                    Stream.of(extractor.call(oldValue)).forEach(prop -> prop.removeListener(listener));
                }
                if (newValue != null) {
                    Stream.of(extractor.call(newValue)).forEach(prop -> prop.addListener(listener));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

A full working demo is below:

**Using extractor approach**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TreeViewDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Task demoTask;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // BUILD DATA
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            Task sub1 = new Task("Sub Task A", rnd.nextBoolean());
            Task sub2 = new Task("Sub Task B", rnd.nextBoolean());

            Task tsk = new Task("Task " + i, rnd.nextBoolean());
            if (demoTask == null) {
                tsk.setName("Demo Task");
                demoTask = tsk;
            }
            tsk.getTasks().addAll(sub1, sub2);
            tasks.addAll(tsk);
        }

        // BUILD TREE ITEMS
        TreeItem<Task> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        final Callback<Task, Observable[]> extractor = task -> new Observable[]{task.getCashFlows()};
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            TreeItem<Task> item = new MyTreeItem(extractor);
            item.setValue(task);
            for (Task subTask : task.getTasks()) {
                TreeItem<Task> subItem = new MyTreeItem(extractor);
                subItem.setValue(subTask);
                item.getChildren().add(subItem);
            }
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        TreeView<Task> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        treeView.setRoot(rootItem);
        treeView.setCellFactory(taskTreeView -> new TreeCell<Task>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Task item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null && !empty) {
                    setText(item.getName() + " (" + item.getCashFlows().size() + ")");
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        Button button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnAction(e -> demoTask.getCashFlows().add(1));

        VBox root = new VBox(button, treeView);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeView Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class MyTreeItem<T> extends TreeItem<T> {
        public MyTreeItem(Callback<T, Observable[]> extractor) {
            if (extractor == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Extractor cannot be null");
            }
            final InvalidationListener listener = e -> Event.fireEvent(this, new TreeModificationEvent<>(TreeItem.<T>valueChangedEvent(), this, getValue()));
            valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (oldValue != null) {
                    Stream.of(extractor.call(oldValue)).forEach(prop -> prop.removeListener(listener));
                }
                if (newValue != null) {
                    Stream.of(extractor.call(newValue)).forEach(prop -> prop.addListener(listener));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class Task {
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        BooleanProperty completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ObservableList<Integer> cashFlows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public Task(String n, boolean c) {
            setName(n);
            setCompleted(c);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public boolean isCompleted() {
            return completed.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty completedProperty() {
            return completed;
        }

        public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
            this.completed.set(completed);
        }

        public ObservableList<Task> getTasks() {
            return tasks;
        }

        public ObservableList<Integer> getCashFlows() {
            return cashFlows;
        }
    }
}
```

**Using Listeners approach (Not recommended, keeping it for record purpose)**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class TreeViewDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Task demoTask;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // BUILD DATA
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            Task sub1 = new Task("Sub Task A", rnd.nextBoolean());
            Task sub2 = new Task("Sub Task B", rnd.nextBoolean());

            Task tsk = new Task("Task " + i, rnd.nextBoolean());
            if (demoTask == null) {
                tsk.setName("Demo Task");
                demoTask = tsk;
            }
            tsk.getTasks().addAll(sub1, sub2);
            tasks.addAll(tsk);
        }
        
        // BUILD TREE ITEMS
        TreeItem<Task> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            TreeItem<Task> item = new TreeItem(task);
            for (Task subTask : task.getTasks()) {
                TreeItem<Task> subItem = new TreeItem(subTask);
                item.getChildren().add(subItem);
            }
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        TreeView<Task> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        treeView.setRoot(rootItem);
        treeView.setCellFactory(taskTreeView -> new MyTreeCell());

        Button button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnAction(e -> demoTask.getCashFlows().add(1));

        VBox root = new VBox(button, treeView);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("TreeView Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class MyTreeCell extends TreeCell<Task> {
        public MyTreeCell() {
            ListChangeListener<? super Integer> listener = p -> updateItem(getItem(), false);
            itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    oldItem.getCashFlows().removeListener(listener);
                }
                if (newItem != null) {
                    newItem.getCashFlows().addListener(listener);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Task item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null && !empty) {
                setText(item.getName() + " (" + item.getCashFlows().size() + ")");
            } else {
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    }

    class Task {
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        BooleanProperty completed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ObservableList<Integer> cashFlows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public Task(String n, boolean c) {
            setName(n);
            setCompleted(c);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public boolean isCompleted() {
            return completed.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty completedProperty() {
            return completed;
        }

        public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
            this.completed.set(completed);
        }

        public ObservableList<Task> getTasks() {
            return tasks;
        }

        public ObservableList<Integer> getCashFlows() {
            return cashFlows;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible, but looks like doctoring on symptons at the a suboptimal place - arguably, of course :) It's the responsibility of the model to notify interested parties, not that of the view to actively did down into model details. Personally, I'm very weary about listeners installed in a cell .. often they turn out to be brittle at unexpected places.

Comment: @kleopatra, I agree to what you said. Can you please let me know the correct way to let the model to update the particular cell when a property of data gets updated. I am interested to know other approaches for this kind of issues. (one of the example is,updating the cell to bold when a property gets updated)

Comment: we should not think cell (== view), but model (== treeItem) - if we need getting notified on whatever changes of the model I regard it as the task of the model to fire a notification. The problem here is that fx doesn't support nested property notification, we have to implement it ourselves (or use 3rd party frameworks which support it): I would go for a custom TreeItem that can be configured with extractors (similar to those provided by FXCollections for observableList).

Comment: the extractor would provide a nested observable of the TreeItem's value to which an InvalidationListener can be un/wired which in turn fires the valueChanged treeModificationEvent - just as @jewelsea suggests in the comment to the question, using an on-the-fly binding, though.

Comment: @kleopatra, updated my answer with the approach you mentioned. And it worked well :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Many GUI frameworks use the Observer pattern to update only the pieces that require update. If you can define each node as an Observer and each piece of data for a node as an Observable then all you need to do is to subscribe those Observers to their correspondent Observable. That way when the data changes it can notify the nodes listening so that only they can change.

For more details check out the Observer pattern of design.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is essentially what the more sophisticated answers to this question do, they just make use of advanced constructs in the JavaFX framework that are manifestations of the Observer pattern.  I think it is useful to understand this.

Comment: Yeah many junior devs in java do not know this, but Java uses the Observer pattern heavily in all their GUI libraries (Hard clients). .Net also uses the same pattern heavily on the same tasks, so understanding this makes it easier to understand the classes and structures that the libraries have available.